# anaconda: boost not found, despite installed package

Tags: python, boost, anaconda

The following command fails in my anaconda Python:

```
>>> import boost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boost'
```

I am on MacOS 10.12.5, using the latest anaconda distribution for Python 3.6 with a Python 2.7 environment. I have installed the boost package (defaults to version 1.61.0) in the default and the Python 2.7 environment through `conda install boost`. `conda list` shows the package. I can see the boost libraries in the file system, i.e., in `~/anaconda/lib` and also in `~/anaconda/envs/Python27/lib/`.

I do not have a deep understanding of anaconda environments and the package management that comes with them. Here are a few version numbers, in the hope that they are useful:

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.3.21
$ which python
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)
$ source activate Python27
$ which python
/Users/me/anaconda/envs/Python27/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Just for the case that it matters; I have boost 1.64.0 installed through homebrew in a non-standard location: `/opt/homebrew`. Anaconda appears in the `PATH` *before* homebrew.

Any help on how to resolve this problem, or even just how to proceed with debugging is highly appreciated. Please comment if you need further information.

Comment: Boost is a collection of c++ libraries -- why are you trying to import them in Python? Even for [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html) this doesn't make any sense, let alone for the rest.

Comment: @Dan Mašek: I know very well what boost is; I have a C++ background myself. I am trying to run someone else's code, which starts by importing boost as a Python module. The mere fact that conda let's me install boost seems like a strong hint that it does make some sense.

Comment: If you look at the [package list](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs), you can see things like `mingw`, `autoconf`, `automake`, pile of C libraries like `libpng` or `zlib`, and so on. So either there's some c++ code as part of your app that would compile into a `boost.pyd`, or it's some different library that also happens to be called `boost`. How is it used in that script? Can you provide some examples of the functions called, or classes used? Or some docs or source from the c++ boost libs to prove that what you claim exists -- I have yet to find some.

Comment: Sorry, I am too unfamiliar with this technology to see which information you need or what could go wrong, so I may have missed to put the "obviously" relevant information first. All the scipt does is to invoke a few functions from a boost::python-based wrapper of a C++ library. Should I have to expect a "boost.dylib" or similar for this to work? I don't even know what Python does in response to an import statement.

Comment: OK. Having installed boost, I'd expect the next step you have to do is compile the c++ code that implements the wrapper. This should produce a shared library exporting a function to initialize the module. I know that on Windows, this lib needs to be renamed to suffix `.pyd`, although I think you may get away with `.so`. Now, assuming this file is in Python module path, you can do `import boost` -- Python will find the `boost.pyd` (or `boost.so`), load it, call its function `initboost`, and if everything goes right, you can use the module in your script.

Comment: Hope that makes some sense. I'm not familiar with Macs, so I can't give you the exact details, but a quick search of SO should shed light on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan! I did not figure it out completely yet, but it seems to be related to the different way libraries are located on MacOS, rpath in particular. This may be related to renaming the lib to so, which at least changes the error (progress!) - that's what I find for my custom library, it does not solve the puzzle for the boost import, for which I have still no clue.